# issues with HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq1gfe8j/3/) and i met some issues using highcharts ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock)).

1. New candle is not random, just copy of previous candle. Methods `UpdateCandle()` and `CreateCandle()` are both using `GenCandle(mode)` to create random candle.
2. however candles are creating and i can update (randomize) last candle but i can't count them using `$('#container').highcharts().series[0].data.length`.
3. Sequence issue: "new,upd, new, upd, ..." and "new, upd, new, new,new, ..." - works fine but "new, new, new" - stops draw candles.

i'm new to highcharts, and spend many hours by searching solution, help!

Comment: Looks potentially buggy to me. Try replacing `series.addPoint(newCandle, true, true);` with `series.addPoint(newCandle, true); series.removePoint(0, true);`. This seems to fix it, correct?

Comment: Thanks, @HalvorStrand changing `addPoint(newCandle, true, true)` to `addPoint(newCandle, true)` creates corect random candles, but i met new issue - can't add more then 63 candles but here [link](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading) displayed 1.7 million data points.

Comment: This is caused by `dataGrouping`, you can disable that: http://jsfiddle.net/cq1gfe8j/5/ I suggest to read more about `dataGrouping` [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping).

Comment: @PawełFus, thank you very much!

Comment: You can mark my answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `dataGrouping`, you can disable that: jsfiddle.net/cq1gfe8j/5 I suggest to read more about `dataGrouping` [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping).